# q/kdb+ windows server setup

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to setup qStudio in windows. While adding a new server, an error message pops up, saying:

Connection does not work.java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection refused: connect.

Used default "Server Properties" configuration:

Host: localhost
Port: 5000
Server Type: KDB
Username:
Password:

Very new to Q/KDB+.. Searched in google, but didn't find the answer. please help! Thank you!

Comment: Never used QStudio but at a guess... Do you have a KDB process running on your localhost at port 5000? Easy way to check if is accessible is just to open a browser to http://localhost:5000 and see if you don't get a 404

Comment: i would change the tag to "kdb" rather than "sql-server". This is nothing to do with sql server ;)

Answer (score 11):

Might be a silly question but have you set up a KDB+ process yet?

1. Download the free version from http://kx.com/software-download.php
2. Explode to `C:\q`, set up `QHOME` environment var to point to this location
3. From dos run `C:\q\w32\q.exe -p 5000` (you now have a database running on localhost:5000)

Then try qStudio again. Should connect fine.

Comment: Is it expected that whenever I launch qStudio, I get a connection error?
It is annoying as it seems that whenever I launch it I need to run `C:\q\w32\q.exe -p 5000` from the DOS in parallel.

Comment: @JejeBelfort I haven't used it in a long time, but it never used to try and automatically connect to a database...

Comment: @ManishPatel Thanks for your answer. Then I guess I will stick to applying point 3. or your answer before launching qStudio...