# How can I start kdb instance in Windows?

Tags: kdb

Hi Im trying to start default `trade.q`:

- Download binaries
- Extract to c:\
- Run c:\q\win32\q.exe

But now (accotding to documentation) trying to start a kdb instance of trade with no success.

```
q> trade.q -p 5001
```

It does not work (no connection via code or `localhost:5001`).

Comment: Is this a typo? Don't think you start q session with `q>`

Comment: I assume he meant `<`  and not `>`, to redirect the contents of the script into q, but in any case, you don't need that. Just `q trade.q -p 5001` is enough.

Comment: If you are in q shell then first do: \l trade.q   and then: \p 5001

Comment: JPC thanks your comment works. I've did started q so session started, so q> displayed in CMD window. But trade.q -p 5001 did not work.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066058/q-kdb-windows-server-setup?noredirect=1#comment37168659_24066058

Comment: "trade.q -p 5001 did not work" -- Rahul has already answered your question. If you're already at the q prompt you can use "\l trade.q" to load the q file. Do "\cd" to figure out where your current directory is if that doesn't work, e.g. you might have to do "\l ../trade.q"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q trade.q -p 5001
```

This video tutorial demonstrates downloading and installing kdb on windows:
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/getting-started-kdb